# mapping lists to dataframe column values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two lists

```
Countrylist = ['USA', 'INDIA', 'SINGAPORE','CHINA','MALAYSIA']
COLORLIST = ['#F1F326', '#D95969', '#D4526E', '#250591', '#FDBB2B']
```

and I have a df with 4 columns:

```
Country Category AVGSPEED AVGVELOCITY
USA     High     345       4634
INDIA   Low      4363      435346
USA     Low      345       346346
CHINA   High     3462      23423
CHINA   Medium   46346     46346
```

I want add a new column to the dataframe such that the color from the list gets mapped to the country seen in the dataframe.
One way am thinking is creating a dict between the two lists, and then mapping the key value to the country column in the dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by dictionary created by `zip` of both lists:

```
Countrylist = ['USA', 'INDIA', 'SINGAPORE','CHINA','MALAYSIA']
COLORLIST = ['#F1F326', '#D95969', '#D4526E', '#250591', '#FDBB2B']

df['Color'] = df['Country'].map(dict(zip(Countrylist, COLORLIST)))
print (df)
  Country Category  AVGSPEED  AVGVELOCITY    Color
0     USA     High       345         4634  #F1F326
1   INDIA      Low      4363       435346  #D95969
2     USA      Low       345       346346  #F1F326
3   CHINA     High      3462        23423  #250591
4   CHINA   Medium     46346        46346  #250591
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's map:

```
df['color'] = df['Country'].map(pd.Series(COLORLIST, index=Countrylist))
```

Output:

```
  Country Category  AVGSPEED  AVGVELOCITY    color
0     USA     High       345         4634  #F1F326
1   INDIA      Low      4363       435346  #D95969
2     USA      Low       345       346346  #F1F326
3   CHINA     High      3462        23423  #250591
4   CHINA   Medium     46346        46346  #250591
```